# Draw a textbox on canvas that contains an image and some drawing over it using fabric js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to draw a textbox on canvas that contains an image and some drawing over it. now I am trying to draw a textbox over it.
When I am trying to initialize canvas object using fabricJS it's making canvas empty first. like..

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas')
```

after this code, it makes canvas empty. but if I initialize this code in the very beginning just after canvas initialized and then I try to add a textbox to that canvas object like...

```
 var text = new fabric.Textbox('A Computer Science Portal', 
 {
    width: 450,
    height: 10,
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
 });
this.canvas.add(text);
```

Then the textbox is not visible. I think it went in the background of the image.
I have already written lots of code for drawing over the canvas not want to draw textbox on the canvas after with all existing drawing and image that is developed in javascript only.

Answer (score -1):

On Fabric you have `bringToFront` use that to keep the text on top.
Here is the official documentation:
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#bringToFront

Sample code:

```js
var image;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var url = "http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/api/SvgImage?"

var text = new fabric.Textbox('TEST', { width: 90, height: 10, top: 30, left: 50 });
this.canvas.add(text);

function loadSVG(url) {
  fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function(objects, options) {
    if (image) canvas.remove(image);
    image = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    image.name = 'sticker';
    canvas.add(image);
    image.scaleToHeight(100);
    image.center();
    image.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.bringToFront(text)
  });
}

loadSVG(url + "color=red")
setTimeout(function() {
  loadSVG(url + "color=blue")
}, 3000);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
```